# Is there any way to write ASP.NET code only inside the panel using C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel, dynamically-generated

I have a page with a panel. What I want to know that is there any way we can write ASP.NET code directly in asp:panel tag on runtime(dynamically)? Any way using AJAX or something? Actually I have a panel that contains some controls and that is to be written several times in a parent panel dynamically.

Comment: you can place a literal and write inside them code, or you can add controls dynamically on the panel

Comment: Ya I want to know about second part. Actually I have a panel that contains some controls and that is to be written several times in a parent panel dynamically.

Comment: there are not many thinks to know, just make the controls, and use the Panel.Controls.Add();

Comment: Are you maybe looking for a `asp:repeater` with an `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: I don't completely understand the question, but have you thought of loading a user control inside the panel?

Comment: @Allensb oh yes I want that. I am an idiot how can I forget about user controls :D thanks for hinting me. and so the question was that a user control that I want to add several times in a panel at runtime

Comment: @AishwaryaShivaPareek Could you add a simple example of the desired html result? It sounds to me like there's a much easier solution than adding controls from code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<% %>` tags and place your code inside them.

For example, You could set the panels width dynamically using:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" 
       BorderColor="#990000" 
       BorderStyle="Solid" 
       BorderWidth="1px" 
       Height="116px" 
       ScrollBars="Both" 
       Width=<% YourWidthFunction() %>>
```

Edit: I now see what you are trying to achieve. From your comment I would not recommend using `Response.Write()`.

I would use:

```
var newPanel = new Panel();
var myLabel = new Label();

newPanel.Controls.Add(myLabel);
```

You can add as many controls as you want to the panel by calling: `newPanel.Controls.Add(control);`

Comment: Good effort, but I don't think this is exactly what the OP wants. It's unclear from the question itself. I understand the effect the 'dynamic' buzzword might have, but this isn't strictly dynamic.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - ah okay. I was assuming he was after something like this, if not I will delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks @DarrenDavies, yet your answer not exactly as what I wanted but it gave me a hint about doing like this <asp:panel><% response.write("TAGS"); %> </asp:panel> now I want to ask that it will work?